# Remember dropdown item OR select if GET

Tags: php, post, get

I currently have this code to remember the last selected item on post.

```
 <select tabindex="1" name="system_customer">
        <option value="Choose">- Choose a Customer -</option>
        <?PHP while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_get_users))
         {
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'"; 
        echo $system_customer == $row['id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
        echo ">".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."</option>";
        } ?>>
    </select>
```

On load (before submitting) the list defaults to "Choose". What I would like to do, is if the URL has `"userid=1"` to select user 1, or if it is `"userid=2"` then select user 2, but keep the code to remember the last selected.

Thank you.

**PS - cannot use mysqli or PDO due to the software I am writing a module for. It is hard coded and encrypted.**

Comment: Highlight or selected??

Comment: Selected - Post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this above your code -

```
$system_customer = "";
if (!empty($_GET['userid'])) {
    $system_customer = $_GET['userid'];
}
```

Then -

```
<select tabindex="1" name="system_customer">
    <option value="Choose">- Choose a Customer -</option>
    <?PHP 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_get_users)) {
       echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'"; 
       echo $system_customer == $row['id'] ? 'selected' : ''; 
       echo ">".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."</option>";
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: It works as it should, except the post doesn't remember the selection if there is no `userid` in the URL.

Comment: Fixed it by removing `$system_customer = "";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use session or cookie 
for exp :

```
<?PHP 
Session_start();
if ( isset ( $_POST['system_customer'] ) ) { 
$_SESSION['SELECTED_USER_ID'] = $_POST['system_customer']; 
?>
```

and you haave to make some changes in you dropdown list

```
<select tabindex="1" name="system_customer">
<option value="Choose">- Choose a Customer -</option>
<?PHP while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_get_users)) {
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'"; 
echo $_SESSION['SELECTED_USER_ID'] == $row['id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
echo ">".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."</option>";
}
 ?>>
</select>
```

in you select form you have to check if session id is equal to row if then put selected attribiut for that option . 
but if you want to save details for long time it's better to use cookie or databases you can't do it in another cases .